# Find and Replace using Regular Expression in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: regex, visual-studio

In my source code, using Visual Studio 2015 I want to replace all javascript calls from a specific folder to its minimized filename. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/common/filename1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/common/filename2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/common/filename3.js"></script>
```

I want to replace with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/common/filename1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/common/filename2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/common/filename3.min.js"></script>
```

I use the following expression:

[image]

What should I put in the "Replace with" field?

Comment: My guess would be that you can wrap parentheses round the bits you want to keep and then refer back to them in the replacement, e.g. `(<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/common/.*)(\.js"></script>)` replaced with `\1.min\2`. But I haven't tried it.

Comment: It's times like this I realise how lucky I am to be a vim user!

Comment: Thank you Matthew, I've made a little correction in the replacement expression to $1.min$2 and voilá, it worked :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a answer following Matthew Strawbridge's suggestion and making a little correction. The find expression is:

```
(<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/common/.*)(\.js"></script>)
```

And the replacement expression is

```
$1.min$2
```

I've tested in my project and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead I would do this...

```
.js"></script>
```

and replace it with

```
 .min.js"></script>
```

Sorry I keep changing this, but this leaves out the regex which is unnecessary

Comment: Updated again (hopefully for the last time)

Comment: I need to use regex because some files are already typed using its minimized filename.